# Can we remove "because I was" without changing the meaning?

Tags: tense, ellipsis

> I fell into a trap, **afraid** I might screw up.
>
> I fell into a trap **because I was afraid** I might screw up.

To me these two can mean the same thing, but I am unsure if this is grammatical or not, or if the meaning is different than intended here.

Comment: They do not mean the same thing. The second one states the reason for why you fell into the trap. The first sentence does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version without "because I was" means that the two things (falling into a trap and being afraid) happen at the same time. On the other hand, it's possible to fall into a trap *because* you were afraid even if, by the time the trap is sprung, you're no longer afraid.